# Characters and landmarks of Ramayana in Mahabharata when both have occurred in different timelines?

Tags: mahabharata, ramayana, epics

Namaste, my question is, when Ramayana has occurred in the Treta Yuga of the 24th MahaYuga, how is it that the landmarks (Ramagiri Hills and Rama Setu) and characters (Vibhishana and Hanuman), though immortal, appear in Mahabharata, which occurred in the Dwapara of 28th MahaYuga. How did these landmarks remain intact when the events have been differentiated by 4 MahaYugas, ie billions and billions of years. Where is the Ravana's Lanka now?

Comment: Difference of 4 mahayugas is not billion of years. That being said what are considered to be landmarks from Ramayana or Mahabharata era cannot be easily traced back.

Comment: @Carmensandiego, how is it not billion years?

Comment: Cuz 1 mahayuga is 4.32 million years. 4 mahagugas ~17 million years. Not billion and billion of years